# Namecheap and domain redirect

Tags: redirect, dns, namecheap

I own a domain name on Namecheap (let's say example.com), and I'd like http(s) calls on this domain to be redirected to my Synology dynamic DNS (example.synology.me). I have tried with CNAME records (example.com -> example.synology.me and *.example.com -> example.synology.me) but this does not work.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: HTTPS uses TLS to verify the hostname in the certificate. URL redirects do not support HTTPS (only HTTP). You would need to deploy a tiny server someplace to receive the initial HTTPS connection and then issue an HTTP Status 3xx.

Comment: I ended up adding an A record to my IP and handle example.com domain directly on my NAS (certificates, reverse proxy, etc)